# Convert Datatype to Integer and drop rows with non integer type values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column whose curren
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` parameter:

```
df['Sno'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sno'], errors='coerce')
df = df[df['Sno'].notna()].astype({'Sno': int})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Sno  test
0   12     5
1   14     5
2   15     7
3   16     8
4   17     9
```

Comment: I obtain the following error on running the first line: raise IntCastingNaNError(
pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Yes, you can do on any other column.